# How can I use D3.CSV to get values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csv, d3.js

I am using Angular-js to construct charts, I need to read CSV file, trasform it using js functions. Then plot the data

I need to know if I can return values from D3.CSV

```
 d3.csv("example.csv", function (error, data) {
    console.log(data) // this will output the data contained in your csv
    //return data;
    });
```

How can I call this function in middle of the other function

```
function doSomethingWithRows(rows) {
  // How to call data here. 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`d3.csv` is an asynchronous function. That is, it runs when the callback returns, rather than in the sequence it appears in the file. Therefore, you need to do any processing of the data within the callback. In your case, you can do something like this:

```
d3.csv("example.csv", function (error, data) {
  doSomethingWithRows(data);
});
```

Comment: But I am using AngularJS to work on charts. I load csv file, do some filtering, then plot filtred data using this chart http://jsfiddle.net/9GSNs/ Should I think to use angularJS to load CSV file ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Is loading the data with D3 not working for you?

Comment: no it works, but I can't inject angularjs code inside d3.csv. it says it's not a function

Comment: It would help if you could describe what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I have 3 steps to do 1-Load CSV file into Data 2-Filter This data 3-Build charts using AngularJS. Now, I have built the chart(with test data) and built my filtering JS function. All what I need is how to load CSV file and get objects.

Comment: I found another solution using AngularJS to load CSV file, but I couldn't find a way how to pass loaded-objects to JS-Function: I posted another question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23444606/how-can-i-call-angularjs-function-in-js-function

Comment: Now, Can you please tell me which is the best approach to tackle this problem. Should I think to use AngularJS to load CSV file or use this approach

Comment: [Here](http://briantford.com/blog/angular-d3) is a detailed post on how to integrate D3 and angular.