# How can I call AngularJS function in JS function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is the first interaction with angularjs.  it's first time. how can I call the function and get the items now in another controlers ?

I am loading CSV file using AngularJS

```
var Mymodule = angular.module('Mymodule', []);
Mymodule.factory('Items', ['$http', function($http){
      var Url   =  "data/ex.csv";
      var Items = $http.get(Url).then(function(response){
         return csvParser(response.data);
      });
      return Items;
    }]);
```

I need to get returned values to do some filtering on the data I have ?

```
  function doSomethingWithRows(rows) {
       //Mymodule.Items
      // How to call data here. 
    }
```

**UPDATE**
Based on first answer

```
<script>
        var Mymodule = angular.module('Mymodule', []);
        Mymodule.factory('Items', ['$http', function($http){
              var Url   =  "data/ex.csv";
              var Items = $http.get(Url).then(function(response){
                 return csvParser(response.data);
              });
              return Items;
            }]);

    var $injector = angular.injector();
    $injector.invoke(['Items', function(Items){ console.log(Items) }]);


</script>
```

error:

```
Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: ItemsProvider <- Items
```

Comment: depends where you placed `doSomethingWithRows` (in a controller, service, etc.?). In AngularJS you use dependency injection for such things.

Comment: I am running test now. the both and the only functions are inside <script></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would extend your factory so you can call a function to get the results.

```
Mymodule.factory('Items', [
  '$http', 
  function($http){
      var Items;          

      this.loadItems = function loadItems() {     
          var Url   =  "data/ex.csv";
          $http.get(Url).then(function(response){
              Items = csvParser(response.data);
          });
      }

      this.returnItems = function returnItems() {
          return Items;
      }
}]);
```

Then in your controller:

```
Mymodule.controller("Controller", [
    "Items",
    function(Items){
        Items.loadItems();

        function doSomethingWithRows(rows) {
            var items = Items.returnItems();
        }
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$injector`:

```
var $injector = angular.injector(["ng", "MyModule"]);
$injector.invoke(['Items', function(Items){ 
  /* do stuff */ 
  console.log(Items);  // e.g. print the Items
}]);
```

`$injector` is used to retrieve object instances as defined by some provider (e.g. your `Items` factory).

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R3nP4/)

Comment: small correction: you need to define the required modules when requesting the injector `var $injector = angular.injector(["ng", "MyModule"]);`