# How to load CSV File in Angular JS to do charts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csv, d3.js

I am working to read a CSV File in AngularJS, then create a chart using the data from the CSV.

CSV file

```
Date,Energy
2001,0.851
2002,0.841
2003,1.000
2004,0.984
2005,1.006
2006,2.769
2007,2.791
```

I use this code to transform the CSV file into data objects

```
var Mymodule = angular.module('Mymodule', []);
Mymodule.factory('Items', ['$http', function($http){
  var Url   =  "data/ex.csv";
  var Items = $http.get(Url).then(function(response){
    return csvParser(response.data);
  });
  return Items;
}]);
```

[Here is chart I use (on jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/rYk26/)

Now I have problems getting the data from the function that transforms the CSV to the function that makes charts. Inspired this thread [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23444606/how-can-i-call-angularjs-function-in-js-function), I tried using injectors but it didn't work out.

Here is what I tried.

```
var $injector = angular.injector(["ng", "MyModule"]);
$injector.invoke(['Items', function(Items){ 
  /* do stuff */ 
  console.log(Items);  // e.g. print the Items
}]);
```

I also tried using `d3.csv` with a global variable:

```
var rows;
d3.csv("path/to/file.csv", function(rows) {
  doSomethingWithRows(rows);
});

function doSomethingWithRows(rows) {
  // USE AngularJS Chart
}
```

My question: how can I load a CSV file and get the data to angularjs-chart to build my chart?

Comment: Is this the question you really wanted to ask? Could you delete your other questions then please?

Answer (score 1):

If you say `var a = b;` then variable `a` gets the result of `b`. The result of `$http.get().then...` is not your items, since your items are not loaded yet.
If you use a promise and call `.then(function(x) {return x}` the value `x` is returned to nowhere.

You can achieve what you want by doing this:

```
var Mymodule = angular.module('Mymodule', []);
Mymodule.factory('Items', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){
  var Url   =  "data/ex.csv";
  
  var ItemsDefer = $q.defer()
  $http.get(Url).then(function(response){
     ItemsDefer.resolve(csvParser(response.data));
  });
  return ItemsDefer.promise;
}]);

Mymodule.controller('Charts', ['$scope', 'Items', function($scope, Items) {
     Items.then(function(parsedCsvData) {
         $scope.chartData = parsedCsvData;
         $scope.initChart();
     });
});
```

And [this great video by John Lindquist explaining angularjs promises](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-promises) can help you.